# small problem with psvita with data

Tags: ps-vita

Just wondering if anyone could give me some help regarding a problem i've been having with my vita, few days back i recently desided to buy "Cladun x2" from the psn store.

Though cutting it short i downloaded some "Edit Data" from the wiki. The data itself was for the US version of the game and i use a EU account.

Main problem is that once i transfered over the edit data, it wasnt visable at all on the psvita. It didnt show up in the content manager and it also didnt show up in application data management. So annoyed as i was, i figured i'd back up all my files on PC and then try a restore.

So i was wondering would these invisible edit data files which werent compatible have been copied as well during back up then restored again? :/ or would the reformat of the memory card have sucessfully gotten rid of them despite not being able to locate them on the vita?

Answer (score 1):

While PS3 and Vita games are region free they have a form of Region Locking where a game wont recognize the DLC for it unless it's from the same region as the game itself,

this is problematic with the Vita as the PSN account is locked onto the memory card unlike the PS3 where you can create separate local profiles for different regions and download all the DLC and play it from 1 local user regardless of region it's PSN account is from

it is quite possible that while this Extra Data is may have been designed for the US version of the game and wont work with the EU version from PSN as there seems to be talk pages on the wiki about US Characters which may support this

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a specific answer for you, but it sounds like you may have missed a step someplace. The detailed instructions are here if you want to step through them.

http://cladunx2thisisa.wikia.com/wiki/Cladun_x2:_This_is_a_Wiki